# What is the purpose of comparing with a random value in [0, 1] in this simulated annealing algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, random, simulated-annealing

In the simulated annealing algorithm at the line number 13 (`IF random([0,1]) ≤ accept THEN`), why do we need to generate a random number to compare with the evolution value with next node? What is the purpose of generating a random number every time without using constant value to compare?

```
1: INITIALIZE startTemperature, endTemperature, maxNumberIterations
2: coolingRate = eˆ(log(endTemperature/startTemperature)/maxNumberIterations)
3: INITIALIZE dataStructures
4: COMPUTE initialSolution
5: INITIALIZE currentSolution, bestSolution, currentObjective, bestObjective
6: currentTemperature = startTemperature ∗ initialObjective
7: globalIteration = 0
8: WHILE currentTemperature > endTemperature ∗ initialObjective DO
9: currentTemperature = currentTemperature ∗ coolingRate
10:EXECUTE randomMove(movesWeight, currentSolution)
11:tentativeObjective = currentObjective + moveCost
12:accept = eˆ(currentObjective − tentativeObjective)/currentTemperature)
13:IF random([0,1]) ≤ accept THEN
14:currentSolution = tentativeSolution
15:IF tentativeObjective < bestObjective THEN
16:bestSolution = tentativeSolution
17:END IF
18:END IF
19:globalIteration = globalIteration +1
20: END WHILE
21: PRINT bestSolution, bestObjective
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose is to execute the following code only with a given probability of `accept`.

If `accept` is 0.3 for instance, a random number between 0 and 1 will be less than or equal to this value only in 30% of all possible cases.

A new random number needs to be drawn in every iteration of the algorithm, otherwise the following code would be executed either *always* or *never*, for a given run of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but when we take the 2 scenarios the same temperature   01) instance is 0.8 and random number 0.9.  02) instance is 0.4 and random number 0.3.  algorithm will select the 02 scenario. isn't it wrong? is there no way to define a constant between 0 to 1 which can execute code without error?

Comment: I'd describe the purpose as to only accept "worse" solutions with the given probability (i.e. allowing the search to escape from local-minima).  note that better solutions (i.e. `accept > 1` here) are always implicitly accepted